# Add template to email Body

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have email service like this:

```
public async Task Execute(string email, string subject, string message)
{
    try
    {
        string toEmail = string.IsNullOrEmpty(email)
                         ? _emailSettings.ToEmail
                         : email;
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage()
        {
            From = new MailAddress(_emailSettings.UsernameEmail, "")
        };
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(toEmail));
        mail.CC.Add(new MailAddress(_emailSettings.CcEmail));

        mail.Subject = "Management System - " + subject;
        mail.Body = message;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;

        using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(_emailSettings.PrimaryDomain, _emailSettings.PrimaryPort))
        {
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_emailSettings.UsernameEmail, _emailSettings.UsernamePassword);
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            await smtp.SendMailAsync(mail);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //do something here
    }
}
```

then I execute it into enother method:

```
public Task SendAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
{
    Execute(email, subject, message).Wait();
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

and I have template email template who have items as:

```
<a  href="{{url}}" target="_blank" </a>
```

How can I call template in body and replace that {{url}} for some variable in my service? So instead  `mail.Body = message;` change to `mail.Body = template;`

Comment: First, you should absolutely get rid of these meaningless, empty `catch` clauses.

Comment: Second, your question seems to simply ask for a `string.Replace` call. I don't see anything SMTP-related at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally keep a template with placeholders such as `{0}`, `{1}`, `{2}` etc, as they fit directly into `string.Format`. So while creating the email, instead of writing `mail.Body = message`, I use:

```
mail.Body = string.Format(template, placeholder1, placeholder2);
```

My template then looks like:

```
Hello {0},

... Please <a href="{1}">click here to do XYZ</a>...
```

Now there is a disadvantage of this method, which is that you must document that `{0}` in template corresponds to `placeholder1` etc.

Alternatively you could use slightly verbose placeholders such as `{FirstName}` or `{LastName}`, and then replace them in the body of email using `template.Replace("{FirstName}", user.FirstName).Replace("{LastName}", user.LastName)`.

Comment: I found it to be most flexible to use [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) for building my email templates. Together with some caching to keep compilation times low, this works awesome, e. g. in my [Zeta Uploader](https://www.zeta-uploader.com) project which sends out thousands of mails a day.

Comment: Assuming my email template is in folder  `HtmlTemplate/EnglishTemplate`  my string format should be . `mail.Body = string.Format("~/HtmlTemplate/EnglishTemplate.html",... );` ?

Comment: @David Actually, in that case you would have to read the content of that file and then use it. Something like `string.Format(fileContent, ...)`.

Comment: @UweKeim That looks quite interesting! You should post an answer with that if you get some time.

Comment: you mean declare variable before as: `var fileContent = "~/HtmlTemplate/EnglishTemplate.html"` then use as your comment?

Comment: @David No. I mean that first you would need to get physical path of the file (using [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1626431/5894241)) and then read the content of the file using `var fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath)`, or something similar.